# CakePHP3 integration test and json data

Tags: json, cakephp, testing, integration, cakephp-3.0

I want to test my restful controller consuming json data. The problem is that I am unable to send the data correctly.

This is how I try to send the data:

```
$this->configRequest([
    'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    ],
]);

$this->post('/api/users', "{'username':'Iason','password':'test'}");

debug($this->_response->body());
```

In my controller, I check the data:

```
if (empty($this->request->data)) {
    throw new BadRequestException("No data");
}
```

The check fails and I get back the error.

If I test my API using Postman, everything works fine. If I try to send the data as an array (which is shown in the manual http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#controller-integration-testing), I don't have any request data in controller either.
I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all that's invalid JSON data, strings must be enclosed in double quotes (`"`), not single quotes (`'`).

> A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be nested.
>
> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes.

**http://www.json.org/**

The other problem is that non-form post data, ie non `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` formatted POST body data has to be set via the `input` option:

```
$this->configRequest([
    'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    ],
    'input' => '{"username":"Iason","password":"test"}'
]);

$this->post('/api/users');
```

Wouldn't hurt if the docs had an example showing that.